# Dataflow job not completed/failed after workers are being started

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have created a dataflow pipeline which read a file from Storage Bucket and just do a simple transform to the data (e.g: trim the spaces).

When I execute the dataflow job, the job started and log shows that the workers are started in a zone, but after that nothing happens. Job never get completed or failed. I had to manually stop the job.

Dataflow job has been executed by a service account having dataflow.worker role, dataflow.developer role and dataflow.objectAdmin role.

Please can someone suggest why the dataflow job is not being completed or why the job not executed after the worker started.

```
2021-02-09 11:01:29.753 GMTWorker configuration: n1-standard-1 in europe-west2-b.
Warning
2021-02-09 11:01:30.015 GMTThe network sdas-global-dev doesn't have rules that open TCP ports 12345-12346 for internal connection with other VMs. Only rules with a target tag 'dataflow' or empty target tags set apply. If you don't specify such a rule, any pipeline with more than one worker that shuffles data will hang. Causes: No firewall rules associated with your network.
Info
2021-02-09 11:01:31.067 GMTExecuting operation Read files/Read+ManageData/ParDo(ManageData)
Info
2021-02-09 11:01:31.115 GMTStarting 1 workers in europe-west2-b...
Warning
2021-02-09 11:07:33.341 GMTThe network sdas-global-dev doesn't have rules that open TCP ports 12345-12346 for internal connection with other VMs. Only rules with a target tag 'dataflow' or empty target tags set apply. If you don't specify such a rule, any pipeline with more than one worker that shuffles data will hang. Causes: No firewall rules associated with your network.
```

Comment: What do the worker and diagnostic logs show? In the Compute Engine panel, are the worker nodes being started? Anything interesting there or in Stackdriver for each instance? More details are needed to help you.

Comment: @JohnHanley There is no log coming to worker or diagnostic logs. The job log only showed that the worker is started. In the right side Job Info panel, resource metrics shows all values as zero; like Current CPUs 0, Current Memory 0 B etc.

I have updated the question with job log details. Thanks.

Comment: When you go to Compute Engine, what does it show for running VMs (not the Dataflow section) "Compute Engine" -> "VM instances"? Also anything in Stackdriver for these VM instances?

Comment: @JohnHanley I just posted the solution. I was running the job in a region as where the VPC was in different region. Thus the worker did not able to spin up. Make the region same as of the VPC and then everything went well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was running the job in a region as where the VPC was in different region. Thus the worker did not able to spin up. Make the region same as of the VPC and then everything went well.

Comment: Can you add more details? 1) Tips on how you diagnosed this problem. 2) Details on conflicting VPCs and how Dataflow launched workers in the wrong VPC. 3) Where were the error messages stored for this problem?

Comment: @JohnHanley
1. First identified in the log where it shows that the no firewall rule is there for your network. (I edited my question, put the log back).
2. Asked my network team to allow my network. They did it. But still the problem remain same. The worker did not spin up yet.
3. Then the person from network team asked me to use the same region where my network belong. Because I was using different region before that.

Comment: I meant add a lot more details to your answer. I know Dataflow well and I do not understand precisely how you created this problem and how to diagnose a solution. I am very curious to understand the details.